# Ajax call php over direct url link

Tags: php, ajax

I have some thoughts about using Ajax to call PHP files. For example PHP files I use to Add/Delete/Accept/Decline someones friends request. Now it's just `<a>` tag with `?user=` variable and redirect to the previous page. So can someone tell me pros and cons of using Ajax to call that PHP insted of normal `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using anchor tag refers to sending data in get request. But on ajax you can use both get and post. Critical data should not be sent in get. So ajax must be the secure way! Also people can manipulate by altering get requests easily. Only to view records you can pass value by anchor tag, for rest its not advisable to use anchor tag. Especially for Adding /Deleting even Accepting/Declining! Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok so my idea is not stupid at all. Great. Thank you man, I will leave this for little more, to see if anyone else posts their opinion.

Comment: great! I am saying user?=123 can be manipulated easily to user?=456. Its not stupid, sometimes these things comes in handy, but not to yours!